# jquery, get element and then copy certain class right before it

Tags: jquery

example page to edit:

```
reply link
post

reply link
post

reply link
post
```

I want for each post to copy *reply link* and append to post. then i **remove** reply link.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('postMessage');

for (var n = elements.length; n--> 0;) 
{
    var elementi = $(".replylink" ).clone();

    elements[n].innerHTML += elementi;

}
```

this wont work

Answer (score 0):

`elements[n].innerHTML+=elementi;` is a *text* operation. You'd end up with `[object Object]` shown on your page.

It sounds like you want to move the reply link. If so, just use jQuery's `append` (which will move the element if it's already elsewhere on the page):

```
$(".postMessage").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var replylink = $this.prevAll(".replylink").first();
    $this.append(replylink);
});
```

The tricky bit there is `$this.prevAll(".replylink").first()`, which does this:

- Builds a list of all `.replylink` elements that are *previous* siblings of this `.postMessage` element, in order from the nearest to this post to the furthest away.
- Takes the first of those, which is the one nearest this `.postMessage`.

Complete example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/IkEdOnaH/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/IkEdOnaH/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Example</title>
  <style>
    .postMessage {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>In a second, the reply links will move <em>into</em> the posts.</p>
  <a href="#" class="replylink">reply 1</a>
  <div class="postMessage">I'm post 1&nbsp;</div>
  <a href="#" class="replylink">reply 2</a>
  <div class="postMessage">I'm post 2&nbsp;</div>
  <a href="#" class="replylink">reply 3</a>
  <div class="postMessage">I'm post 3&nbsp;</div>
  <script>
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".postMessage").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var replylink = $this.prevAll(".replylink").first();
        $this.append(replylink);
      });
    }, 1000);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```